# Creating a factor from a numeric column vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, factors

I have a numeric column of weights (`df$weight0`) in a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) `df`. I want to create a new column `df$weight1` which is a `factor` based on the values in `df$weight0`.

If the value in `df$weight0` is less than or equal to 170, the corresponding value in `df$weight1` should be 1 but if the value in `df$weight0` is greater than 170,the corresponding value in `df$weight1` should be 2.

The code below is what I have tried but it gives a single value not a vector.

```
  if (i<=170){
    i==1
  }else{
    i==2
  }
}
```

Comment: `df$weight1 <- (df$weight0>170)+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `cut()` for discretizizing continuous variables by intervals

For such kind of interval categorization, there is the very useful function `cut`.

```
nums <- nums <- runif(100, min=0, max=300) # n = 100 random numbers between 0 and 300
factorized_num <- cut(nums, c(-Inf, 170, +Inf))
# you can name the categories as you want:
levels(factorized_num) <- c(1, 2) # first interval 1, next interval 2
# with include.lowest=TRUE or FALSE you can determine whether lower limit is <= or <
```

## Or use `Vectorize()` to vectorize non-vectorized functions

```
# define for one case:
categorize <- function(i) if (i<=170) 1 else 2
# then vectorize it:
categorize <- Vectorize(categorize)
```

Now you can use it:

```
categories <- categorize(nums)
head(categories) ## 1 2 1 1 ...
```

I prefer this - out of my experience - much more over `ifelse()` because you have full control over the single case.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried with the cut method  ```wcgs$w8t<-cut(wcgs$weight0,breaks = c(78,170,320), labels = c("<= 170 lbs", "> 170 lbs"), include.lowest=T)```

Comment: nice! The best is you include/name all limits (and `-Inf` and `+Inf` are thereby useful if there are no limits).

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` can use vectorized input:

```
df$weight1 <- ifelse(df$weight0<=170,1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were checking the value of i, not the values in your df. Also the assignment of your new columns was not implemented. Try the following.

```
for (i in wcgs$weight0){
  if (wcgs$weight0[i]<=170){
    wcgs$weight1[i] <- 1
  }else{
    wcgs$weight1[i] <- 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I use wcgs$weight1[i] to change the value at that index

Answer (score 0):

Using `case_when` from the package [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(df$weight1 = case_when(df$weight0 =< 170 ~ 1,
                                     df$weight0 > 170 ~ 2))
```

`case_when()` helps to formulate `if-else` construct and `mutate()` modifies or adds columns.